# Using AllExcept but taking slicers into account too

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have some DAX code to create a calculated column that gives the sum of the values in "Qty" column grouped by the distinct values in the "Family" and "Code" columns.

I want to modify that code so it also takes slicers into account too.

I have tried a lot of the solutions already but I haven't been able to figure this out for my case.

It has to be a calculated column because I will be using it in a slicer.

This is the code I have:

```
SumQtyByFamily = CALCULATE(SUM('MyTable'[Qty]),ALLEXCEPT('MyTable','MyTable'[Family],'MyTable'[Code]))
```

But it doesn't take slicers into account.

Comment: Can you share some data ?

Comment: Calculated columns can not take slicers in account.

Comment: Looking at RADO comment that calculated columns cannot take slicers into account, I see that I may be approaching this in completely the wrong way.  So, overall the scenario is this, I have a table that shows Qty broken down by Family and Code.  I want to be able to filter this table by Qty so that user can filter down to only those Family/Code combos where total Qty is > x.  I also have slicers on date etc that affect the table. Note that the Qty for a Family and Code is obtained by summing multiple rows.